# Ajax fails to pass html page as parameter to code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vb.net

I am working on a task to convert a webpage to pdf file using SelectPdf. SelectPdf does not support dynamic pages. So I want to use Ajax to pass the webpage as html.

For some reason when I passed ordinary string it works but when I change to use a variable (with html as value) it doesn't. I don't know whether the html content is too large, however I tried with less content and still the same issue. Any help will be appreciated.

The project is language is VB.Net, the page is vbhtml and code behind is a controller.

Please see below the code I have implemented:

**VIEW**

```
           var btn = $('#BtnCreateHtmlToPdf');

           btn.click(function () {

            var theHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

            //Just to see there is a value
            alert(theHtml)  

            $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: "/CreatHtmlToPdf/CreatePdf",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: { HTML: theHtml }
                })
                .done(function (results) {
                    alert("Html data: " + results);
                });
            });
           });
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
Public Class CreatHtmlToPdfController
    Inherits Controller

    ' GET: CreatHtmlToPdf
    Function Index() As ActionResult

        Return View()
    End Function

    <HttpPost()>
    Function CreatePdf(ByVal HTML As String) As ActionResult

        Dim doc As PdfDocument

        ' read parameters from the webpage
        Dim htmlString As String = HTML

        ' instantiate a html to pdf converter object
        Dim converter As New HtmlToPdf()

        ' create a new pdf document converting an url
        If (HTML <> String.Empty) Then

            doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString)


        End If


        ' save pdf document
        Dim pdf As Byte() = doc.Save()

        ' close pdf document
        doc.Close()

        ' return resulted pdf document
        Dim fileResult As FileResult = New FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf")
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Results_page.pdf"
        Return fileResult

    End Function

    'Declaration
    'Public Property EnablePageMethods As Boolean

End Class
```

Comment: have you tried dataType to json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding [ValidateInput(false)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute above your CreatePdf function to prevent the standard ASP MVC validation that prevents posting HTML.

```
<HttpPost()> _
<ValidateInput(false)> _
Function CreatePdf(ByVal HTML As String) As ActionResult
```

Optionally if you're accepting a ViewModel class you can add the [AllowHTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute to that single property that holds your HTML data.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am having the html value now but one problem is that the value is toggling between Nothing and the html value passed. So by the time the library is called to convert the value then is Nothing leading to a bug in the code.

Is there a way I can stop the parameter toggling. I suspect multiple request being made to the Ajax but I only click the button once.

Comment: Try If HTML Is Not Nothing AndAlso HTML <> String.Empty.  Also, put all that doc.Save(), doc.Close(), etc code in that If block.

Comment: Unfortunately, is still behaving the same way . Before and now it behave like is a loop during the run cycle. Check changes made:


            If HTML IsNot Nothing AndAlso HTML <> String.Empty Then

                doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString)
                pdf = doc.Save()

                doc.Close()
            End If

Comment: Thanks NoAlias. I have got it working. I didn't removed the form around the button so I was using the form as well as the Ajax to post. Thanks for your great help.